# Possible to display timezone in OS X menu bar?

Tags: macos, time-zone

Since I have trouble keeping my standard/DST straight in my head, I'd like to see the 3-letter timezone abbreviation with the date/time on my menu bar in OS X.

I tried customizing the short time format in the Language & Region settings, but that did not change what shows on the menu bar.

Any other settings that I can tweak to get what I'm looking for? Any free/inexpensive app to do it?

Answer (score 0):

[iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) will do this.  It's NOT free ($16) but it's a great menu-bar add-on (it does tons of other things, not just time!).  I've been a happy user for years.